# Inserir somente itens em um DropDownList que já foram utilizados no cadastro principal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de inserir no `DropDownList` somente os setores que já foram utilizados no cadastro de contatos.

Em meu `ContatosController` no `ActionResult` no método `Index` fiz isto, mas o problema que esta acontecendo é que esta inserindo somente o ultimo, pelo jeito terei de inserir em uma nova lista e depois inserir esta lista no `DropDownList`.

Gostaria de saber qual a maneira correta

```
//AQUI ESTOU SEPARANDO EM GRUPOS OS SETORES JÁ UTILIZADOS EM CONTATOS
var setoresEmCadastro = db.Contatos.GroupBy(s => s.SetorId).ToList();

//AQUI PEGO O CÓDIGO DE setoresEmCadastro E PESQUISO
foreach (var item in setoresEmCadastro)
{
     var s = db.Setores.Where(a => a.SetorId == item.Key);

     //INSIRO NO COMBOBOX
     ViewBag.SetorID = new SelectList(s, "SetorId", "Nome");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido da maneira abaixo.

**Mas deixo em aberto. a quem tenha uma melhor solução.**

```
var setoresEmCadastro = db.Contatos.GroupBy(s => s.SetorId).ToList();

   var sd = new List<Setor>();

        foreach (var item in setoresEmCadastro)
        {
            var s = db.Setores.Where(a => a.SetorId == item.Key).ToList() ;

            var fdp = new Setor
            {
                SetorId = s[0].SetorId,
                Nome = s[0].Nome
            };

            sd.Add(fdp);
        }

        ViewBag.SetorID = new SelectList(sd, "SetorId", "Nome");
```